# Multiple clickable icons in grid column

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, grid, telerik, icons

I am using a Telerik MVC Grid and I am trying to get multiple clickable icons in one column.

What I really want to achieve is to do this not via command, but in a normal column, using own icon with "onclick" event.

Did try this, but does not really work.

```
columns.Template(@<text><span class='viewicon' onclick='view'><span class='modifyicon' onclick='modify'></text>)
```

When I tried : `columns.Template(@<text><span class='viewicon' onclick='view'></text>)`, the event does not get attached to the icon.

Did manage to do this via, but I do not want to have via Command:

```
columns.Command(command => {
                 command.Custom("View").Click("view").IconClass("k-icon k-i-preview k-i-eye");     

                 command.Custom("Modify").Click("modify").IconClass("k-icon k-i-track-changes"); });
```

Maybe you have some useful input on the topic.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I managed this and maybe someone also needs something similar, this is how I solved it:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Action).ClientTemplate(
   "<span class='k-icon k-i-preview k-i-eye' title='View' onclick='view()'></span>" +
   "<span class='k-icon k-i-track-changes' title='Modify'  onclick='modify()'></span>" +
    "<span class='k-icon k-i-delete k-i-trash' title='Delete' onclick='delete()'></span>");
})
```